# jQuery - combination with one() and on() functions

Tags: jquery, function, bind, live, combinations

I want to use the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) jQuery function that executes a specific function only one time, but in combination with the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery function because the elements are not rendered yet.

So, I will need to use the 'on' function in this way in order to bind the function for not rendered elements.

```
$(document).on('click',',myElement',function(){



});
```

How to implement the 'one' function in order to execute my code only for the first click of the element?

Comment: Do you mean once per element or once in total?

Comment: The function is doing some calculations and performing actions over other elements. If the function is executed twice or more, there will be no problem at all. Anyway, I feel it wrong to execute some JavaScript code on each click as  only once execution is enough. That's my concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The `.one()` method supports event delegation. This will mean the callback runs once, rather than once for each matching element:

```
$(document).one('click', '.myElement', function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

However, if you mean that you want the event handler to execute once for each element that matches the selector, the easiest solution may be to add some data to the element once the handler has been executed. You can then check for the presence of that data to determine whether or not to continue with the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myElement', function() {
    if (!$(this).data("done")) {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        $(this).data("done", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It will run once in total, while the OP wants once per element, I believe.

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes more sense. It's not that clear from the question.